# geometry_msgs/Vector2?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an extension of `geometry_msgs` including 2D types, such as `geometry_msgs/Vector2`?
I don't seem to find such a package on Github, for example.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248568/geometry_msgs/vector2-?/) by [antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/23427/antonio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2016-11-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're looking to store 2D positions or poses, perhaps the [Point](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Point.html) or [Pose2D](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose2D.html) types in `geometry_msgs` could work?

For `Point`, just ignore the `z` member. If you don't care about orientation, ignore `theta` in `Pose2D`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/23427/antonio/) on 2016-11-23**:
Right; my concern was mostly about keeping the message type semantically consistent with the content; but of course we can reuse `Point` for 2D.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-24**:
Well, I guess it's a bit of a point for discussion, but using `Pose2D` for this seems like a good fit: it encodes a position in a 2D space, with an associated orientation.

You could consider submitting a PR that adds a `Vector2` (or maybe `Point2D`) to `geometry_msgs` though.